# Observability of plates - Proof of the improvement (condition Observability)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, differential-topology, optimal-control

hey guys I was learning about the `Observability of plates` and I came across integral equality I didn't get how they got into it from the integral

here is the details about everything

I listed the details about where I was learning and the information

here

[page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfXbk.png)

[page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezLhc.png)

[page 3, also here where the question marks didn't get it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wErz2.png)

[page 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfY3w.png)

[page 5 where I didn't understand anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2j5P.png)

If you could guide me into how to understand as the slides isn't described well enough

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: in page 5 under the name proof of the improvement -> how to calculate that integral?